# GitHub API for assigning user to a selected issue

Tags: github, github-api

Is there any API for assigning user to an issue? Any example or any pointer to the API name is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Edit an Issue](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#edit-an-issue) endpoint:

> ```
> PATCH /repos/:owner/:repo/issues/:number
> ```

It accepts a string parameter `assignee`:

> Login for the user that this issue should be assigned to.

You should be able to get away with just sending something like this:

```
{
  "assignee": "octocat"
}
```